# Accumulator pattern for ruby_block or other non-template resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want to create a chef [accumulator](https://docs.chef.io/accumulators/) custom resource that accumulates data from multiple instances, and then uses a `ruby_block` resource to modify an existing file.

All the examples of accumulators that I can find use a template resource or similar where it is possible to accumulate more state in the properties of a sub-resource, such as the `variables` property of the `template` resource. But in my case there isn't any appropriate property for the `ruby_block` resource type.

Is there somewhere else I could store accumulator state, that I could reference in the ruby block? Perhaps a class variable?

For example I would like to do something like this:

```rb
action :add do 
    items[new_resource.host] = {'user' => new_resource.user , "password" => new_resource.password}
    path = new_resource.file_path
    with_run_context :root do
        edit_resource(:ruby_block, "set-auth #{path}")
            block do 
                json = JSON.parse(IO.read(path))
                #elided handling if file doesn't exist yet
                json['auths'] = items
                IO.write(path, json.to_json)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But I'm not sure how to implement `items`, especially if I want to keep things separate for different values of the `file_path` property.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code?